# AWS api gateway curl -X POST read from json file Missing Authentication Token

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

i have one problem with aws Api Gateway , then i use the following command all works and my script in lambda works well:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"username\":\"Alexis\",\"groupname\":\"vendor.basic\",\"repositoryname\":\"newone\",\"repdescription\":\"Summm\",\"servicename\":\"codecommit.amazonaws.com\",\"sender\":\"Zorro55@gmail.com\",\"reciept\":\"Zorro55@gmail.com\",\"topicArn\":\"arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:701177775058:PasswordSender\"}" https://yigjgmptwj.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/New
```

But i need to read and post json from the file named file.json, and if i put my json contain in file.json and try use this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://yigjgmptwj.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/New.json -d @file.json
```

I have an error message : {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"} , maybe somebody knows what i should to do? maybe i need to take some policies to my roles or what? help plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You append a `.json` extension in the url. The error caused by API Gateway since it unable to locate the path `../prod/New.json`.

Comment: Now i try this :  curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://yigjgmptwj.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/new  -d @jtest.json , and having same error .

Comment: Try this `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://yigjgmptwj.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/New -d @file.json`  .. I just removed the .json extension while the path /New still remains.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: Emm , Popoi , look , but now if i call this command it back me message : {"errorMessage": "string indices must be integers", "errorType": "TypeError", "stackTrace": [["/var/task/lambda_function.py", 20, "lambda_handler", "UserName=event['username']"]]}  , but i just put this json file string in to a command it works , maybe you know why it happen? i just copy my json contain in to a file.json , nothing else .

Comment: So this is an error from the Lambda, right? I think the error is related to JSON parsing error in the Lambda function. The value in the `file.json` should be a `json`, instead of a string. Can you try to write the content of `file.json` in JSON, for instance, `{"username":"Alexis","groupname":"vendor.basic ... "topicArn":"arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:701177775058:PasswordSender"}`.

Comment: awesome!! :o you really good, now it works like i need it ! Thanks for answer , i glad , that in a stack there are such clever people.